# How to detect speed on collision

Tags: unity

The problem with OnCollisionEnter2d is that it only gets called when there is a collision but what I wanted is to get the current speed of object at the moment of impact until the object stops moving. So that I if the object stops moving after impact I will call another function.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2D collision){
   Debug.Log(speed); //problem this will only give the speed at the moment of impact
   if(speed <= 0){
     blah blah
   }
}
```

I also tried putting speed variable on the Update()

```
void Update(){
     var currentVelocity = player_rb.velocity;
     speed = currentVelocity.magnitude;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using either OnColllisionStay2D or a coroutine?

Comment: I havent tried OnCollisionStay2D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Coroutine

```
void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2D collision){
   StartCoroutine(DoSomethingWhenStopped());
}

IEnumerator DoSomethingWhenStopped(){
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => player_rb.velocity.magnitude <= 0.01);
    DoSomething();
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html

Comment: Note that if the object bounces off of several objects in a row without stopping, with this method we could end up with several copies of the coroutine all running at once, and calling `DoSomething()` repeatedly when the object stops and they all complete.

Comment: That's true. Easy to store a reference to the coroutine and call `StopCoroutine()` if needed